# How to only make one cell selectable

Tags: iphone, selection, cell, tableview

In my normal tableview I got a bunch of switches and segments, and I don't want them to be selectable, so I set:

```
tableView.allowsSelection = FALSE;
```

Now one of the cells, I want to point to a new view, and thereby make it selectable. But there's no cell.allowSelection or anything, how do I solve this? How do I make it, so that it can be pushed and direct you to another view? I don't want them all to be selectable, since that's ugly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an `allowsSelection` property on cells, but there is a similiar property.

Set `cell.selectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` for cells you don't want to the user to be able to select.

(You will have to set `table.allowsSelection` back to `YES`.)

Configured this way, you'll still get `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for any cell the user taps; just ignore it for cells that you don't intend to be selectable. (Thanks tc.)

Comment: The user *can* select those cells (you still get -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:); it's just not visible.

Comment: Yes, you just ignore those selections. If the selection doesn't appear and doesn't do anything, it might as well not be there. I'll add a note about that, though. :)

Comment: Works like a charm. And thanks tc, for pointing out the fact that the delegate gets called anyway...